# Como é que eu posso adicionar elementos numa array multidimensional?

Tags: php, array

como é que faço para adicionar elementos a uma array multidimensional. Por exemplo em vez de criar uma array em PHP desta  forma:

```
$i = 0;
$aArray[$i]['title'][] = 'teste';
$aArray[$i]['link'][] = 'teste de link';
```

Poder fazer assim

```
$aArray[$i] = array( 'title' => ??????, 'link' => ????? )
```

o ???? deve adicionar um elemento ao final dessa array

Comment: De uma olhada neste Post parece ser a mesma duvida que voce tem.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19099153

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você deve estar querendo simplificar o processo.

Não sei se aplica ao seu caso, mas uma maneira de fazer isso é usando as referências - através do sinal `&`.

```
$test =& $array[1]['test'];

$test[] = 'stack';

$test[] = 'overflow';

print_r($array);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [test] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stack
                    [1] => overflow
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Interessante. Mas esse tipo de operações não foram descontinuadas?

Comment: Não. Atribuição por referência só é depreciado em instâncias de classes

Comment: Ok, já tive a ver e está óptimo! abraço

Comment: por isso amo php.. nem em sonho pode-se fazer isso em linguagens "sérias" rsrsrs